# AttributeError: '_RequestGlobals' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, blueprint

My code line is as follow:

```
post = Post(title=form.title.data, slug=form.slug.data, body=form.body.data, user=g.user)
```

Please note that I am using Blueprint, and created user in my `users.py`, and now accessing

`g.user` to add in `backref = 'user'`

and facing the error

```
 AttributeError: '_RequestGlobals' object has no attribute 'user'
```

In users.py I set the g.user as:

```
@users.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
  form = SignupForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
      return render_template('users/signup.html', form=form)
    else:
      g.user = User(form.firstname.data, form.lastname.data, form.email.data, form.password.data)
      db.session.add(g.user)
      db.session.commit()
      session['email'] = g.user.email
      return redirect(url_for('users.profile'))

  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('users/signup.html', form=form)
```

Comment: And how and when is `g.user` set?

Comment: Please check my updated post, I set it in the signup methon in users.py, and using it in posts.py.

Comment: The `g` globals are **per request**, not per server. The next request `g` is empty again.

Comment: so how can I resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `g` globals are **per request**, not per server. The next request `g` is empty again. Quoting the [Application Globals documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#application-globals):

> To share data that is valid **for one request only** from one function to another, a global variable is not good enough because it would break in threaded environments. Flask provides you with a special object **that ensures it is only valid for the active request** and that will return different values for each request.

(emphasis mine)

Use a [`@app.before_request` handler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) to load the user again for each request, looking for the `session['email']` key. You may want to think about using something more secure to track users from request to request. An add-on like [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) can handle all this for you.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this, then i will let you know.